# Spiting filter values into conditions sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a filter and condition in a function, which works for only one condition

i:e '='
    I want it to work for all condition like  `' IN'`, `' >='`, `'<='`

Here is the Code

```
declare @filter VARCHAR(1000)  
    DECLARE @TempFilter VARCHAR(1000)  
    declare @Condition VARCHAR(1000)  
    set @Condition='Blocked'  
    SET @Filter=N'Blocked=0 and TYPE = 2 and ID = 1635729'  
    SET @Condition=@Condition+'='  
    SELECT   

    @TempFilter=SUBSTRING(@Filter,CHARINDEX(@Condition,@Filter),LEN(@Filter))  
    IF CHARINDEX('and',@TempFilter)=0  
    BEGIN  
    SET @Filter=SUBSTRING(@Filter,CHARINDEX(@Condition,@Filter)+LEN(@Condition),  
    LEN(@Filter)-LEN(@Condition)-LEN(@TempFilter))  
    END  
    ELSE  
    BEGIN  
    SET @Filter=SUBSTRING(@Filter,CHARINDEX(@Condition,@Filter)+LEN(@Condition),  
    CHARINDEX(' ',@TempFilter)-LEN(@Condition))  
    END
```

Please help or suggest.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the code does and provide some examples? Are you trying to parse SQL or build SQL?

Comment: Please run the query you will get result as '0'. If you set  @Condition='ID' , you will get '1635729' , but this wont work like a @Filter=N'Blocked>=0 and TYPE =2 and ID = 1635729' with  set @condition='blocked'

Comment: I think you are missing a loop as I only get "ocked=0" for `@Condition='ID'`. In any case, to properly parse SQL you will need to write quite a lot of code as you need to handle tab characters, multiple spaces and potentially identifiers containing spaces e.g. `[My Column1]`. My questions is why do you need this?

Comment: Yes. I missed below codes   SET @Filter=REPLACE(@Filter,'  ',' ')
    SET @Filter=REPLACE(@Filter,'= ','=')
    SET @Filter=REPLACE(@Filter,' =','='). I want to filter values from the strings by providing my required string, for ex. if I pass 'blocked' I should get '>=0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test this code

```
DECLARE @tempFilter VARCHAR(1000)  
declare @condition VARCHAR(1000)  
declare @filter VARCHAR(1000)
declare @operator VARCHAR(1000)
declare @trimmedFilter VARCHAR(1000)
set @Condition='Blocked'  
SET @filter=N'Blocked IN(0) and TYPE > = 2 and ID IN (1635729,15454)'  


WHILE LEN(@Filter) > 0
BEGIN
   IF CHARINDEX(' and',@filter)<> 0
   begin
   SET @TempFilter = RIGHT ( @filter , LEN(@filter) - CHARINDEX(' and',@filter)-4)
   SET @filter = LEFT ( @filter , CHARINDEX(' and',@filter))
   end
   SET @trimmedFilter =  REPLACE(@filter,' ','')
   set @operator =
   case
   when CHARINDEX('NOTIN(',@trimmedFilter) <> 0 then 'NOTIN' 
   when CHARINDEX('IN(',@trimmedFilter) <> 0 then 'IN'
   when CHARINDEX('>=',@trimmedFilter) <> 0  then '>='
   when CHARINDEX('<=',@trimmedFilter) <> 0 then '<='
   else '='
   end
   IF CHARINDEX(@Condition,@filter) <> 0
   BEGIN
      SET @filter = REPLACE(RIGHT(@trimmedFilter,LEN(@trimmedFilter) - CHARINDEX(@operator,@trimmedFilter)+1), 'NOTIN', 'NOT IN')
      BREAK
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      SET @filter = @TempFilter         
      CONTINUE
   END
END
```

Comment: Malainine, It works for all the operators, Only 'NOT IN' operator is not working.

Comment: you can add it in the case statement

Comment: @syncdm2012 I edited the code to comply with the condition 'NOT IN'